# Need to find file path of files in current eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin that requires retrieval of path/filename of all files that are open in the current workspace window.

The code that I have written, successfully retrieves the filenames of currently open java files, but is unable to retrieve the path/file of all other file types such as xml, jsp, css etc.

The code I have used so far is:-

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    IEditorReference[] ref = page.getEditorReferences();

    List<IEditorReference> javaEditors = new ArrayList<IEditorReference>();

    //Checks if all the reference id's match the active editor's id
    for (IEditorReference reference : ref) {
        if ("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor".equals(reference.getId())){
            javaEditors.add(reference);
        }
    }

    if(javaEditors != null){
        for(IEditorReference aRef : javaEditors){
            System.out.println("File info: " + aRef.getName());
        }
    }
```

What I need help with is - to retrieve (file path + file name) for all open files (any file type) in the current open workspace/editor. The above code only is able to get me the file names of Java classes open in the current editor.

Comment: Be aware of the fact that not every editor will be associated with an actual file, or with only 1 file. Some editors can be working on either a) no file at all (a "logical" structure that is backed by something other than a file), or b) more than one file. @greg-449's answer handles those by just returning null; depending on your requirements you might have to do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should deal with all editors that are actually editing a single file:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorReference[] refs = page.getEditorReferences();

for (IEditorReference reference : refs) {

   IEditorInput input = reference.gtEditorInput();

   IPath path = getPathFromEditorInput(input);
   if (path != null)
    {
      System.out.println(path.toOSString());
    }
}


private static IPath getPathFromEditorInput(IEditorInput input)
{
  if (input instanceof ILocationProvider)
    return ((ILocationProvider)input).getPath(input);

  if (input instanceof IURIEditorInput)
   {
     URI uri = ((IURIEditorInput)input).getURI();
     if (uri != null)
      {
        IPath path = URIUtil.toPath(uri);
        if (path != null)
          return path;
      }
   }

  if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput)
   {
     IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();
     if (file != null)
      return file.getLocation();
   }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: To be really robust, it should probably try to adapt the IEditorInput instead of calling `instanceof`. It's possible that some editors use an adaptable input type that doesn't implement those interfaces directly.

Comment: Also, `IFile#getLocation()` is for the *on-disk* location, not the path in the workspace (which may not physically be under the workspace's directory). Use `IFile#getFullPath()`. FWIW, org.eclipse.core.resources and its APIs are relatively consistent at this distinction between what it means between locations and paths.

Comment: @nitind Some editors may be editing files which are not in the workspace. My code returns the full path for everything.

Comment: @greg-449 Which doesn't contradict anything you wrote, other than the path in the workspace isn't the same thing as the on-disk location. They are different API calls once you've determined that the input is from an `IResource`.

Comment: Thank you for the above solutions! Using the code provided above I was able to retrieve the file path+name. It was exactly what I needed! (There were some packages that were needed for the above code to run, and weren't covered by the plugin dependencies, however with some digging around I was able to get it).